# If instead Carl had play replaced every number $x$ by $1 + x$, what would be the sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, arithmetic

**Carl have a list of real numbers, whose sum is $40$. If Carl replaces every number $x$ on the list by $1 - x$, the sum of the new numbers will be $20$. If instead Carl had play replaced every number $x$ by $1 + x$, what would be the sum?**

My awfully messy and definitely not understandable solution: 
Let S = the sum without every number x
n = number of x’s in the list of real numbers 
$S + xn = 40$
$S + n - xn = 20$
$40 - xn + n - xn = 20$
$n - 2xn = -20$ 
Ok so as you can’t see I am not going anywhere with this solution so only one thing I can rely on, the online community.. I’m very confused and I would be happy I found anyone lend me a hand in this one..

The answer from the answer key is 100 by the way..

Comment: The problem is badly stated because $x$ is used for all the numbers on the list.  As written, one could imagine you change all the $\frac 13$s to $\frac 23$s and leave all the other numbers the same.  The intent is to have a list of numbers, which we can index by $i$ and refer to as $x_i$.  We then replace each $x_i$ with $1-x_i$ and so on.  The answer by hgmath does this.

Answer (score 6):

$sum=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=40$

$(1-a_1)+(1-a_2)+\ldots+(1-a_n)=n-sum$

$n-40=20\to n=60$

$(1+a_1)+(1+a_2)+\ldots+(1+a_n)=n+sum=60+40$

done.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Calling the numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n$, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (1+x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i) + 2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$